How to Ensure Atomicity with Cloudinary and MongoDB
I am working on a social media platform where users can upload media files (images, videos, etc.) to Cloudinary, and I store the returned URL of that media in my MongoDB database. The media upload is successful, but in some cases, the database saving operation fails. In such a situation, I want to delete the uploaded media from Cloudinary to avoid having orphaned files.
I have written the following code where I am using Cloudinary for file uploads and MongoDB for saving post data. I am using Mongoose transactions to ensure atomicity for the database operations, and if the database save fails, I am calling cloudinary.uploader.destroy() to delete the media from Cloudinary in the catch block.
However, I am concerned about a scenario where the delete operation on Cloudinary fails after the database transaction has failed. In this case, my media will remain on Cloudinary, causing inconsistencies.
Here's the relevant part of my code
Cloudinary configuration and utility functions
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

// Configuration
cloudinary.config({ 
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME, 
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, 
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET 
});

const opts = {
    overwrite:true,
    invalidate:true,
    resource_type:"auto",
    folder: "Socialsphere"
};

// Upload media to cloudinary
exports.cloudinaryUpload = (image) => { // image = base64
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, opts, (error, result) => {
            if (result && result.secure_url) {
                return resolve(result);
            }
            return reject({message: error.message});
        });
    });
};

// Delete media from cloudinary
exports.cloudinaryDelete = async (id) => {
    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(id);
};

Controller Code
const Post = require('../Models/Post');
const Profile = require('../Models/Profile');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { cloudinaryDelete, cloudinaryUpload } = require('../Utiles/Cloudinary');

exports.CreateNewPost = async (req, res) => {
    // Implementing transaction
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    let cloudinaryResult = null;

    try {
        const { caption, url, type } = req.body;
        const { Email } = req;

        if (!url) {
            return res.status(409).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Post creation failed, try again'
            });
        }

        // Uploading media to Cloudinary
        cloudinaryResult = await cloudinaryUpload(url);
        const fileUrl = cloudinaryResult.secure_url;

        // Saving post to the database
        const userPost = new Post({ Url: fileUrl, Caption: caption, Type: type });
        await userPost.save({ session });

        // Finding user by email and updating their post array
        const userProfile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
            { Email: Email },
            { $push: { Post: userPost._id } },
            { new: true, session }
        );

        if (!userProfile) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'User not found, please login and try again'
            });
        }

        // Commit the transaction
        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Post created successfully'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        // If any operation fails, delete the uploaded file from Cloudinary
        if (cloudinaryResult && cloudinaryResult.public_id) {
            await cloudinaryDelete(cloudinaryResult.public_id);
        }

        // Abort the transaction
        await session.abortTransaction();
        session.endSession();

        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Post creation failed, try again'
        });
    }
};

My Question:

How can I ensure atomicity across both Cloudinary and MongoDB operations?
What should I do if the delete operation on Cloudinary fails after a database failure? How can I handle such failures to avoid orphaned media files on Cloudinary?
Are there any best practices for ensuring eventual consistency in cases where external services like Cloudinary are involved in transactions with a database?

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve this flow and make it more robust. Thanks!

I work at Cloudinary and I can address your 3rd point:
If you are worried about orphaned images being left on Cloudinary, you could do the following:

On Mongo, find the list of public_id values. These are the images that should exist.
On Cloudinary, use the Admin API to list available resources.
Create a diff and delete any asset that is not found in Mongo.

You could perhaps have this as a scheduled job that runs every month/quarter and cleans up the system.

could you please share some resources that I can go through to learn more about scheduled jobs, including how to use them?
